# Stability of formyl chloride

Tags: stability

Why is formyl chloride unstable? I know it is just a combination of CO and HCl. But why it is unstable whereas other acyl chlorides are stable, like acetyl chloride?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is unlike other acyl chlorides as formyl chloride dissolves in water. At the same time, it reacts vigorously with it, and no other acyl chlorides produce carbon monoxide and hydrochloric acid.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for its solubility in water?

Comment: Because of its structure (HCOCl), there is hydrogen bonding between the H- atom and water.